# TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="address", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.5.1) getting this error while deploying contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, web3js, ethers.js, hardhat

here is my contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity ^0.8;
contract Project {
 
struct Card { uint256 id; string title; string about; string skills; }

event CardCreated(uint256 indexed id, string title, string about, string skills);

mapping(uint256 => Card) private cards;
uint256 private cardCount;

function createCard(string memory title, string memory about, string memory skills) public {
    cardCount++;
    cards[cardCount] = Card(cardCount, title, about, skills);
    emit CardCreated(cardCount, title, about, skills);
}

function getCard(uint256 id) public view returns (Card memory) {
    return cards[id];
}
}
```

here is my deploy.js file

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const Contract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Project");

  // console.log(Contract);
  const contract = await Contract.deploy();
  // console.log("this is contract:", contract);
  await contract.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(`Contract Address: ${contract.address}`);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

here is the error I'm getting
Network used to deploy contract is ganache.

```
TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="address", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.5.1)
    at makeError (C:\Users\susha\OneDrive\Desktop\practice\checking\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:670:21)
    at assert (C:\Users\susha\OneDrive\Desktop\practice\checking\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:694:25)
    at assertArgument (C:\Users\susha\OneDrive\Desktop\practice\checking\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:706:5)
    at Interface.getFunctionName (C:\Users\susha\OneDrive\Desktop\practice\checking\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\interface.ts:542:23)
    at buildWrappedMethod (C:\Users\susha\OneDrive\Desktop\practice\checking\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:334:34)
    at BaseContract.getFunction (C:\Users\susha\OneDrive\Desktop\practice\checking\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:841:22)
    at Object.get (C:\Users\susha\OneDrive\Desktop\practice\checking\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:747:39)
    at main (C:\Users\susha\OneDrive\Desktop\practice\checking\scripts\deploy.js:11:45)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'key',
  value: 'address'
}
```

I tried re-create the hardhat file and change the contract but still getting same error repeatedly

Comment: What versions of `hardhat` and `ethers` are you using? The `waitForDeployment()` is available in ethers v6 but not in previous versions, so that is a possible cause.

Comment: I tried it without using waitForDeployment() and using the latest versions of both ethers and hardhat

Answer (score 2):

`ethers` version 6 uses `getAddress()` function to retrieve the contract address, while the previous version 5 uses `.address` property.

Replace

```
console.log(`Contract Address: ${contract.address}`);
```

with

```
const address = await contract.getAddress();
console.log(`Contract Address: ${address}`);
```

Docs: https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/contract/#BaseContract-getAddress

Comment: thnk u it worked